# A keyboard shortcut to the top menu bar music sources

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, menu-bar, shortcut-menu

I have this icon in my Mac menu bar:
[image]

It's very useful to toggle between two different audio source apps I have open at the same time. Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle between them (ie I want to toggle between music and some noise cancelling app like White Noise)